# How to get the number of Array in IDAPython?

Tags: reverse-engineering, malware, ida

Would you please tell me how to get the number of Array in IDAPython ?

For Example, how to get the number of Items in `xrefs[]` array ?

```
xrefs = CodeRefsTo(ea,1)<br>
print("the number(count) of xrefs is %i" ?) <--- How to write ?
```

Comment: Try `len(xrefs)`.

Comment: Thank you, I try to do "len(xrefs) but there is an error which is that " error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: When it's a generator you can try `len(list(xrefs))`. Xref count is typically small, converting it to a list should create no performance problems.

Comment: great ! thank you so much !